# Выгрузка массива из localStorage

Tags: массивы, angularjs, localstorage

Код в начале страницы для записи данных в массив при загрузке:

```
$scope.users = [];
var local = localStorage.getItem("info");
if(local){
    $scope.users.push(local);
}
else(alert("не работает =("));
```

Есть массив:

```
$scope.users = [
    {
        "name": "Homer S.",
        "phone": "(999)321-467",
        "message": "Сообщение на внутренней странице Homer S."
    }
];
```

В который добавляются данные из инпутов через функцию:

```
$scope.addUser = function(){
    if ($scope.addName){
    $scope.users.push({
        name:$scope.addName, 
        phone:$scope.addPhone, 
        message:$scope.addMessage
    });
        localStorage.setItem("info", JSON.stringify($scope.users));
        var restoredSession = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("info"));
        console.log(restoredSession);
}
    else{alert("bad idea")}
    $scope.addName = '';
    $scope.addPhone = '';
    $scope.addMessage = '';
};
```

Сами инпуты с формой:

```
<form ng-submit="addUser()" class="form-inline">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputName2">Имя</label>
                    <input ng-model="addName" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Телефон</label>
                    <input ng-model="addPhone" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="(999)333-444">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea ng-model="addMessage" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Введите ваше сообщение..."></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Добавить</button>
                </form>
```

Собственно при перезагрузке самый первый кусок кода передает в массив $scope.users объект local в котором хранятся данные из localStorage, проблема в том что объект в массив передается (хоть это и странно), но данные конечно никакие не выводятся, к тому же при добавлении данных и еще одной перезагрузке, новые данные добавляются как еще один массив и получается массив в массиве и т.д.
Я не знаю как корректно передать данные из хранилища что бы при загрузке страницы атрибуты: "name", "phone", "message", получили соответствующие значения. Выводится белая строка в таблице просто.
P.S. есть мысль что надо сохранить правильнее конечно же и как то просто запушить в массив users данные, что бы все было на своих местах.

Comment: Код в самом начале `localStorage.getItem("info");`  замените на `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("info"))`. И `$scope.users.push(local);` замените на `$scope.users =local;`. Если не будет ошибок - оформлю как ответ.

Comment: Ошибку выдал когда более одной записи(
увы и ах(

Comment: Извините, сегодня телепат штатный отпуск взял. Какая ошибка-то?))

Comment: angular.js:9037 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=user%20in%20users%20%7C%20orderBy%3AorderProp&p1=object%3A004
    at MINERR_ASSET:22
    at angular.js:18664
    at Object.fn (angular.js:11299)
    at g.$digest (angular.js:11395)
    at g.$apply (angular.js:11634)
    at angular.js:1285
    at Object.d [as invoke] (angular.js:3609)
    at c (angular.js:1283)
    at Wb (angular.js:1297)
    at Oc (angular.js:1246)

Comment: это браузер выплюнул, с одной записью все ок, сохраняет и выводит нормально, когда 2 выдает это

Comment: Все решилось через оф сайт, там есть эта ошибка и есть способ устранения. Возникает при повторении ключей в ng-repeat, лечится добавлением "track by $index" в атрибут ng-repeat. 
Степану огромное спасибо за помощь! Побольше бы таких людей.

Comment: Строго говоря, исходя из структуры ваших данных в `users` ошибки `ngRepeat:dupes` не должно было быть. Возможно, у вас еще не все до конца правильно.

Comment: Сейчас там ничего нет, туда записываются данные с формы, а так по умолчанию массив пустой. Данные через метод addUser попадают.
Это же метод глобального объекта $scope ?